# Flutter noob needs some help: screen dont show the result

Tags: flutter

I try to use the info class as a sample for multiple classes but my problem is when i run the app i only can see a white background. Sorry for the long code I am very new at programming and try to be better soon :)

```
            class kaminfeuerinfo extends StatefulWidget {
              @override
              _kaminfeuerinfoState createState() => _kaminfeuerinfoState();
            }
            
            class _kaminfeuerinfoState extends State<kaminfeuerinfo> {
              
             List <Info> inhalt = [
               Info(name: 'hallo', beschreibung: '1', preis: '2', kilo: 'f', details: 'f,', artikelnummer: 'd',zutaten: 'f',
                verkehrsbezeichnung: 'z', inverkehrbringer: 'h', kj: 'h', kcal: 'h',fett: 'h',
                saeure: 'g', kohlenhydrate: 'h',zucker: 'k', eiweiss: 't', salz: 't')
             ];
              
            
            
              
              
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                  children: 
                    inhalt.map((inhalt) => info (inhalt: inhalt)).toList(),
                ),
                ),
                );
              }
            }
        
        class Info {
          String name;
          String beschreibung;
          String preis;
          String kilo;
          String details;
          String artikelnummer;
          String zutaten;
          String verkehrsbezeichnung;
          String inverkehrbringer;
          String kj;
          String kcal;
          String fett;
          String saeure;
          String kohlenhydrate;
          String zucker;
          String eiweiss;
          String salz;
        
          Info({this.name,this.beschreibung, this.preis, this.kilo, this.details, this.artikelnummer, this.zutaten, this.verkehrsbezeichnung,
           this.inverkehrbringer, this.kj, this.kcal, this.fett, this.saeure, this.kohlenhydrate, this.zucker, this.eiweiss, this.salz,});
        }
```

this isn't all of the code because the code takes more than 500 rows, but i hope it is enough for you too help me with my problem:)

```
class info extends StatelessWidget {
 
  final Info inhalt;
  info ({this.inhalt});
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showSearch(context: context, delegate: suchen());
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.search))
        ],
        title: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/logo_465x320.png",
          width: 150,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  inhalt.name,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 7.0,
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                child: AutoSizeText(
                  inhalt.beschreibung,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  maxLines: 15,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                ),
                width: 130,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 7.0,
              ),
              Container(
                child: Carousel(
                  images: [
                    Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/kenia.jpg",
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/tee2.jpg",
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/tee.jpg",
                    ),
                  ],
                  autoplay: false,
                  dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
                  indicatorBgPadding: 5.0,
                  dotPosition: DotPosition.bottomRight,
                  dotColor: Colors.white38,
                  dotIncreasedColor: Colors.white60,
                  dotIncreaseSize: 3,
                  dotSize: 3,
                  dotSpacing: 12,
                ),
                height: 200.0,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Container(
                child: SizedBox(
                    width: 200.0,
                    height: 250.0,
                    child: DefaultTabController(
                      length: 2,
                      child: Scaffold(
                        appBar: AppBar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                            title: Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  child: Text(
                                    inhalt.preis,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.black),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: Text(
                                    inhalt.kilo,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.black),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "inkl. 7% MwSt.",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.black),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            centerTitle: true,
                            bottom: PreferredSize(
                              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
                              child: TabBar(
                                tabs: [
                                  Tab(
                                    text: "Details",
                                  ),
                                  Tab(
                                    text: "Informationen",
                                  ),
                                ],
                                isScrollable: true,
                                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                                indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                                labelColor: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            )),
                        body: TabBarView(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                              child: Text(
                                inhalt.details,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the list on the screen as a list you will have to use ListView.builder here on your State class:

```
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                  children: 
                    inhalt.map((inhalt) => info (inhalt: inhalt)).toList(),
                ),
                ),
                );
              }
            }
```

Here you have detailed documentation I advise you to get familiar with:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html